# Mock/Change value of external function pointer variable

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to mock function pointers from an external library for unit-testing for now with [FFF (Fake Function Framework)](https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff) but other suggestions are also welcome.

```c++
//lib.h

...
typedef INT64 (__stdcall *fptr_lib_function) (LONG nItemID, 
    LONG nInfoType, LPBOOL lpSuccess); 
...
extern fptr_lib_function lib_function;
...
```

```
//lib.cpp:

...
fptr_lib_function lib_function;
...
LONG __stdcall RetrieveFunctionPointers()
{
    ...
    lib_function = (fptr_lib_function) GetProcAddress(Hdl, "lib_function");
    ...
}
```

Regardless of what I'm doing, I either get a SEGVAULT, meaning the function was not mocked or a linker error "Multiple definitions". The example below is throwing a SEGVAULT.

```c++
// myfile.h

#ifndef MYFILE_H
#define MYFILE_H
bool some_other_function_calling_lib_function();
#endif
```

```
// myfile.cpp

#include "subfolder/lib.cpp"

bool some_other_function_calling_lib_function() {
    bool success = false;
    int result = lib_function(1, 1, &success);
    return result < 0;
}
```

```
// myfile.test.cpp

#include <fff/fff.h>
#include "myfile.h"

FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(INT64, lib_function, LONG, LONG, LPBOOL);

TEST("My_Test") {
    lib_function_fake.return_val = -1;
    ASSERT(some_other_function_calling_lib_function());
}
```

I have the following structure and compile commands:

```
<root> <- Execute compile commands here
  |- external
        | - xwf
        |    | - myfile.cpp
        |    | - myfile.test.cpp
        |    | - myfile.h
        |    | - subfolder
        |          | - lib.h
        |          | - lib.cpp
        | - fff
             | - fff.h

g++ -I external -std=c++17 -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DSTRICT -DNOMINMAX -DDEBUG -c -MMD -MP -MF build/xwf/myfile.test.d -o build/xwf/myfile.test.o external/xwf/myfile.test.cpp
# rinse and repeat for all the other files.

g++ -I external -std=c++17 -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DSTRICT -DNOMINMAX -DDEBUG -ggdb3 -DDEBUG build/test.o build/xwf/myfile.test.o build/xwf/subfolder/lib.o -o build/test.exe
```

Basically the only idea I came up with is replacing the entire `lib.cpp` file with my own implementation for the tests. Is this what I have to do or are there other solutions?

Comment: `function_fake.return_val` does not match your function definition `lib_function`. Run your test program in a debugger and check where the segfault occurs.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to change that function name. edited it.

Comment: If you get linker errors about multiple definitions you must make sure you don't link the original function when you want to use the fake function or vice versa. This can be a bit difficult in C. You should show in your question some more example code including a real `lib_function` and `some_other_function_calling_lib_function` and the commands/Makefile you use to build the test program. If both `lib_function` and `some_other_function_calling_lib_function` are in the same compilation unit you might have to split the source file or use conditional compilation or preprocessor tricks.

Comment: The difficulty also applies to C++ if you use functions that are not members of a class. With classes you might be able to create a subclass of the class that contains the method to be replaced, mock some method(s) of the subclass and make sure your code under test uses the subclass instead of the original class. Replacing methoids in a subclass requires that the methods are virtual. Replacing the original class with the subclass for the unit test requires that your code under test allows to somehow pass an object of the original class or subclass.

Comment: Ok, I added the information you wanted. I just try to keep it as simple as possible, which is why I didn't have the other files.

Comment: Do you really have `#include "subfolder/lib.cpp"` in `myfile.cpp` or do you mean `#include "subfolder/lib.h"`? If you include `lib.cpp` and also compile it separately you will get duplicate symbols. Does your test executable need to use any other functions from `lib.cpp` that are not to be replaced with fake functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case, `lib_function` in `lib.cpp` is a function pointer that gets initialized by `RetrieveFunctionPointers`.

This means after calling `RetrieveFunctionPointers()` you can easily change the function pointer to point to a different function, i.e. to a fake/mock function. In this case the fake/mock function must have a different name to avoid duplicate (conflicting) symbols.

I suggest something like this:

```
// myfile.test.cpp

#include <fff/fff.h>
#include "myfile.h"

// use a different name to avoid conflicts
FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(INT64, mock_lib_function, LONG, LONG, LPBOOL);

TEST("My_Test") {
    /* I don't know if there is a better place for this assignment.
     * If it is also required for other tests, maybe you can put it 
     * in a setup function for the unit tests or maybe at the place
     * where RetrieveFunctionPointers() is called. */
    lib_function = &mock_lib_function;

    mock_lib_function_fake.return_val = -1;
    // now this function will call the fake/mock function via the function pointer
    ASSERT(some_other_function_calling_lib_function());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that works. I always had the `lib_function = &mock_lib_function` outside of the `TEST` macro which only gave me compiler error `lib_function does not name a type`. But inside the macro it works.

Comment: @Teharez If you try the assignment at file scope outside of a function, this is not valid in C or C++, but it should be possible to do it in other functions as well.